# Is it possible to save the location of a symbol that is moving on a polyline?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

So I am working on this project:[image: this project] So, I have that path symbols moving on a polyline, and as you know I want to simulate the speed of the real plane movement, and the plane needs to travel a lot of km so it takes a lot of time. So my question is if it is possible to save the movement of the plane so when i close my browser and open it again it remains at the same place where it was the last time I saw it or if it is possible for the plane to keep moving so it doesn't come back to the beginning when I open the browser again.

Thx a lot any help will be very appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want to know the position of the plane even if you close and reopen the browser, that means you need to store it on the backend. So, when you load the page, you retrieve the position of each plane from a database and then you draw them in the right position. After that you poll ever X seconds to redraw them in the updated position.
That means the movement algorithm that updates the position of each plane cannot depend on the frontend (client side), you need to do it on the backend.

Another idea, if you know the departure, arrival and current time, you can calculate the position of the plane and then draw it. And recalculate the position on client-side every X seconds to update the plane position. The departure and arrival times should be stored on a database in the backend/server-side. The current time should be retrieved from the backend/server-side as well since you cannot rely on the client's current time.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! It seems a little bit of of my knowledge but i will do some research!!

Comment: I've edited my answer to give you another idea about how to achieve what you want.

Comment: Oh, perfect my friend thx a lot!